# Floating DIV in table cell in IE

Tags: javascript, css, html, column-width

first fo all, sorry for my english. I am trying to do dragable and resizible table columns in pure Javascript. I inserted inside a cell 2 areas, one for draging (div) and 2nd for resizing (span) like you can see in example bellow. Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE8.

Problem is during resizing when div doesn't fit in cell and jump under cell as you can see "Column1" in [image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/308877/ie8.png). I would suggest property "overflow:hidden" should fix it, but no luck.

CSS:

```
.ui-column-resizable
{
  float:right;
  height:20px !important;
  display:inline;
  cursor:w-resize;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  background-color:blue;
  margin: -2px -2px -2px 0;
}


.ui-column-draggable
{
  height:17px;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:yellow;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
column.innerHTML = "<span class='ui-column-resizable'>&nbsp;</span>" + 
                    "<div class='ui-column-draggable'>" +  
                      column.innerHTML +
                    "</div>";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A5kVs/2/

Comment: Try to make a demonstration of what you have made so far using *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)*. If you do this, we can experiment with your problem to find a solution.

Comment: @oFce Why don't you use CSS classes?

Comment: @thirtydot Ok, I will try jsFiddle.

Comment: @Šime Vidas That's not problem. I have it there cause I'm still experimenting with this.

Comment: @oFce The code above is not valid. You cannot span strings in multiple lines.

Comment: @thirtydot Here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/A5kVs/1/ But inside jsFiddle it works in IE8 fine, I don't get it. Maybe you will see some mistake

Comment: @Šime Vidas I made extra new lines for you to make it readable. Here it is OK http://jsfiddle.net/A5kVs/1/

Comment: @oFce If you want to make your code more readable, use CSS classes. Then I would be able to inspect the CSS code and see what's going on. I cannot read the code when it's compressed inside the style attribute.

Comment: doesn't `c.innerHtml = "a" + c.innerHtml + "b";` make create it grow continuously. by the 10th time that code is run you'd have `aaaaaaaaaamycbbbbbbbbbb`

Comment: @Šime Vidas I separated styles to CSS classes, hope it's more readable.

Comment: @Fun Mun Pieng It doesn't. I'm doing this only in onLoad().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it...

HTML:

```
<td>             
    <div class="drag">
        Column 1
        <div class="resize"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.drag {
    position:relative;
    background-color:yellow;
    padding:1px 10px 1px 5px;
    cursor:move;
}

.resize {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    right:0;
    width:5px;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    cursor:w-resize;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/5mzgP/3/